# How to access variable stored in POST into GET fnction?

Tags: node.js, express, post, ejs

My post method is a part of an API that I am using to upload files and to store them in a folder in a local directory. When the user uploads the file it gets stored in the local directory and the path of the image is logged in the console. I am trying to render the path that is logged in the POST method to the EJS template that I am rendering in the get route. I am new to express and node is there any way I can do this? Here is my code:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: './upload/images',
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        return cb(null, `${file.fieldname}_${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`)
    }
})

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
   limits:{
       fileSize: 10485760
   }
})

app.post("/upload", upload.single('profile'), (req, res) => {
    res.redirect("/main")
    let imgPath = req.file.path;
    console.log(imgPath);
})

function errHandler(err, req, res, next) {
    if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
        res.json({
            success: 0,
            message: err.message
        })
    }
}
app.use(errHandler);
```

*This logs* **"upload\images\profile_1609158104360.jpg"**

**My get function in which I am trying to access the loged path from the /upload post route**

```
app.get("/main", function  (req, res) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        // res.render("main");
        User.find({ "secret": {$ne: null}}, function(err, foundUser, imgPath){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }else{
                if(foundUser){
                    res.render("main", {
                        usersWithSecrets: foundUser,
                        usersWithImage: imgPath
                    });
                    console.log(imgPath);
                }
            }
        }
        );
    } else {
        res.redirect("/login");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant. On post /upload you return redirect. Than browser makes get /main, which is totally different request.

Comment: is there any way that I can do it I've tried res.json previously which also didn't work.

Comment: Its other request, that has no connection to previous unless you create it somehow. By looking on your code i can judge that you are saving profile picture. When saving picture, you could save profile picture path to DB, that will solve all your problems.

Comment: Thank you so much my friend I'll try that right now and see if that works :) thank you so much for the help